# Airflow wrong execution_date for timezone aware DAGs

Tags: timezone, jinja2, airflow

We're using Airflow v2.2.3 on Kubernetes (KubernetesExecutor),
our environment requires a DAG pre-customer, and each customer can be in a different timezone.

Each DAG should be scheduled in its own timezone at midnight,
and I saw that it can be achieved using Airflow's [timezone aware DAGs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/timezone.html#time-zone-aware-dags)

so configuring timezone aware `start_date` for each DAG worked and made each DAG to execute in its own timezone midnight:

```
start_date_utc = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=2)).replace(
        hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

timezone = pendulum.timezone(get_customer_timezone(customer))
START_DATE = start_date_utc.replace(tzinfo=timezone)

default_args = {
        "owner": "owner",
        "depends_on_past": False,
        "start_date": START_DATE,
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id,
    schedule_interval="0 0 * * *",
    default_args=default_args,
    tags=[cusotmer_name]
)

date = '{{ execution_date | ds }}'

operator_args = {
    "customer_date": date,
}
```

My problem is that both the [jinja template](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html#templates-ref) and dag_run the `execution_date` (dag_run.logical_date) is still in UTC, and was not adjusted based on the DAGs timezone.

That causes unexpected behavior when running DAGs in different timezones tho `execution_date` of DAGs with timezone offset earlier than UTC is wrong (2 days before and not 1)

I need some advice please on how can we change the `execution_date` based on the DAGs timezone

thanks

Comment: For example: `{{ execution_date.in_timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')` ?

Comment: @Elad that's cool, but each DAG have its own timezone 
so I'll need to access the dag's timezone from within the template

Comment: You have it in `dag.timezone`

Comment: thanks @Elad ,
I was able to solve it as you suggested using: 
`{{ dag_run.logical_date.astimezone(dag.timezone) }}` in template,

I wondered if the execution_date for timezone aware dags can be in DAGs timezone, cause currently as far as I can see in docs it's only in UTC ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of `execution_date` is in UTC.
To convert to different time zone you can do:

```
{{ execution_date.in_timezone('Europe/Amsterdam') }}
```

If you set timezone in your DAG you can access it from `dag.timezone` and use it Jinja.

```
{{ dag_run.execution_date.astimezone(dag.timezone) }}
```

You already noticed that `execution_date` is deprecated macro so you should use `logical_date` as:

```
{{ dag_run.logical_date.astimezone(dag.timezone) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/timezone.html#templates

```
import pendulum

local_tz = pendulum.timezone("Europe/Amsterdam")
local_tz.convert(logical_date)
```